# Disadvantages/perils of enabling Anonymous Access on IIS

Tags: iis

Google isn't being very friendly in terms of this are so I'll just ask the question here instead...

Just wondering are there any disadvantages or perils that I should be aware should I decide to enable Anonymous access on IIS 6 or 7 for a web app that runs internally? (i.e. never exposed to the Internet)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One disadvantage to anonymous access in an intranet is that it prevents you from having any control over user access for the web app.

For example, by using windows authentication, you can allow authenticated users access to your web app, thereby forcing users to be authenticated inside your domain.  This is an extra security measure for intranet, and the usual implementation for an intranet web application in an enterprise environment.

It will be hard to audit access using IIS logs, as it will always be the anonymous identity used.  This may impact any enterprise auditing requirements that may be in place.  Again using windows authentication can allow all domain users to access the web app, while providing accurate auditing and access log information.